# multiline assignment to a single shell variable

Tags: bash, shell

recently i started exploring shell scripting.

i wrote a simple shell script(git hook) to check which are all the modified files in my local repository.Shell script works fine.

**my script**

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
git fetch && git log ORIG_HEAD..origin/master --pretty=format:"%s - %ar by %an %h"
```

**output**

```
post-merge check 7 - 30 seconds ago by xyz f917898
post-merge check 6 - 54 seconds ago by xyz 98399c8
```

I want to mail output of my shell script to  my friend.

i tried like this

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
changed_files = `git fetch && git log ORIG_HEAD..origin/master --pretty=format:"%s - %ar by %an %h"`
echo "$changed_files" | mailx -s "changes made to local repo" abcd@example.com
```

but it is leading me to

```
.git/hooks/post-merge: 2: .git/hooks/post-merge: changed_files: not found
```

can any body suggest me how to achieve this?

I can do this with writing output to an text file and attach that file and send a mail.
But i am curious about sending in a single shot.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of those spaces around the `=`:

```
changed_files=`git ...
```

In `bash`, the line:

```
changed_files = something
```

means to run the `changed_files` executable (which doesn't exist in this case, hence the error), passing two parameters, `=` and `something`.